# How to parse and get the values for parameters from output list of a JIRA query using R?

Tags: r, jira, jira-rest-api

There is a **parsed json** output list from a **JIRA** query where there are '**n**' number of  **Issue Key** values as shown below:

```
library(httr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://somesite.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project = Project"
res <- GET(url , authenticate("username", "password", "basic") )
parsed_json <- content(res, "parsed")

parsed_json$total
[1] 4

number_of_issues  <- parsed_json$total

parsed_json$issues[[1]]$key
[1] "Project-111"
parsed_json$issues[[2]]$key
[1] "Project-112"
parsed_json$issues[[3]]$key
[1] "Project-113"
parsed_json$issues[[4]]$key
[1] "Project-114"

IssuesList <- paste0("parsed_json$issues[[", 1:number_of_issues,"]]$key")

IssuesList
[1] "parsed_json$issues[[1]]$key" "parsed_json$issues[[2]]$key" "parsed_json$issues[[3]]$key" "parsed_json$issues[[4]]$key"
```

I wish to get for the issue key values from the list. I am struck at how to get the value of parsed_json$issues[[?]]$key  from the list. The closest question in this forum was [R: How to convert the output-list from a FQL-query into a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760439/r-how-to-convert-the-output-list-from-a-fql-query-into-a-data-frame). But, I could not extract the values for individual parameters. Moreover, since the arguments in the generated list are not of same length, I could not use this solution. Any suggestion to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and sharing it for people like me who is planning to query JIRA using REST API and R.

```
library(httr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://somesite.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project = Project"
res <- GET(url , authenticate("username", "password", "basic") )
parsed_json <- content(res, "parsed")
parsed_json <- enframe(unlist(parsed_json, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE))

# Select the parameters which has values for all the issues in the JIRA query output list 
# to avoid  "arguments in the generated list are not of same length" error message while unstacking.

df<- filter(parsed_json, (name == "issues.key" | name == "issues.fields.status.name" | name == "issues.fields.summary" |  
                          name == "issues.fields.assignee.displayName" | name == "issues.fields.created" | 
                          name == "issues.fields.updated"...))
df <- unstack(as.data.frame(df), value ~ name)
```